# Priority Queue cost?

Tags: priority-queue

I wrote a program to calculate the median of a running sequence using two priority queues min and max. By comparing the input with the current median, it is put on a queue depending on its value. By comparing queue sizes the median can is determined.

I have to hypothesize and test the execution time of the program. From testing and plotting the graph for different input sizes I can see the execution time is indeed linear.

This surprises me, the reason being is I thought the bigger the queues the longer it takes to place the correct value at the root ? or is the size of the queue irrelevant to placing the correct value at the root (as it seems in my results).

If someone could elaborate on the cost of priority queue that would be very great.

Comment: Can you describe your algorithm in more details? Like, how do you "put on a queue depending on its value"? And how you determine the median based on queue sizes?

Comment: I compare the input with the current median and place it on the max queue if < median and min queue if > median. If the queues are equal size the median need not be changed. If one is greater by more than 1 then the root is swapped to the other queue and the new median is either the root of one of the queues (upper or lower median) or the average of the roots. Theres more to it than that but thats the fundamentals of it.

Comment: As you have said "root", I believe you're using the max-heap and min-heap implementation of priority queue? It has the cost of `O(log n)`

Comment: Yes, your'e completely right. I had another look at my data and a mental blank on my part the results are showing O(log n) cost perfectly. Thankyou very much